# 「mysqldump --all-databases」内容をデータベースへインポートしたいのですが、

Tags: mysql

**前提**
・色々試行錯誤しているので、何回かやり直している状態です

---

**Q1.「mysqldump --all-databases」で取得したDUMPデータをインポートする際、既存同名があった場合、上書きされるでしょうか？**
・データベースは「IF NOT EXISTS」がコメントアウトされている(?)から、上書きされる？

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/
```

・テーブルは削除後、作成される？

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `テーブル名`;
```

---

**Q2.データベース構成をインストール直後の構成に戻すことは可能でしょうか？**
・何回かdumpデータをインストールしたのですが、可能ならその前の状態へ戻したい

---

**環境**
・MySQL5.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

はじめに、
"IF EXISTS"は存在した場合
"IF NOT EXISTS"は存在しない場合に実行されます。

> Q1.「mysqldump --all-databases」で取得したDUMPデータをインポートする際、既存同名があった場合、上書きされるでしょうか？

いえ、存在した場合DROPされ、そのあとに再作成されるはずです。
DUMPデータを見ると、DROP TABLE文のあとにCREATE TABLE文が書かれていると思います。
また、存在しているが "IF NOT EXISTS" を入れずにCREATE TABLEを発行した場合、エラーが発生するはずです。

```
ERROR 1007 (HY000): Can't create database 'NewYork'; database exists
```

> データベース構成をインストール直後の構成に戻すことは可能でしょうか？

DBを一旦削除し、再度インストールするのがいいかもしれません。

また、何度も試すような可能性があるなら、Dockerでmysqlサーバを用意してそれにdumpを適用する方法を取ると良いかもしれません。使い捨てがかなり楽になるとおもいます。(かならずしもDockerである必要はありません。)

Answer (score 1):

> 上書きされるでしょうか？

SQLダンプは、INSERT文で出力されるので、データは追加されます。
また、オプションで`

```
  --add-drop-database　

  --add-drop-table
```

を指定しなければ、DATABASEやTABLEは削除されません。

これ以上失うもの（データ）が無いなら、一度データファイルを削除して、DATABASEをCREATEし直すことで初期状態に戻せます。